# Identify X Y coordinates of polygons and add them to the attribute table in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, coordinates, xy

I have a polygon shapefile which I have imported into QGIS, however it does not display X Y coordinates.  Is there a way that I can identify the coordinate for the centroid of the polygon and display this in the attribute table?

Comment: It's certainly possible, but first you need to identify the meaning of "centroid",  since there are several options, and not all of them are "inside" the polygon.

Answer (score 6):

The QGIS field calculator can do it with these built-in functions:

```
 x($geometry)
 y($geometry)
```

Make sure to create a new field of type `real`, with an appropriate accuracy. You can even use a virtual field to avoid changing the datasource.

Comment: @inc42, the expressions `x(centroid($geometry))` and `y(centroid($geometry))` were the right answer.

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca the `x()` and `y()` functions return the x resp. y values of the centroid of non-point geometries. No need for calculating the centroid twice.

Comment: @inc42, In that case, seems to me better to include that information and new expressions, or a new answer.

Comment: It would be great to add details to the answer.